# 3D voxel Display in matlab

Tags: matlab, voxel

I have a grid, it is 3D and it stores a number.

Here is an example of my grid if it is 2*2*2:

```
(:, :, 1) -> [0, 0;
              0, 0]
(:, :, 2) -> [0, 0;
              0, 0]
```

The number 0 would usually be a number that I would like to represent with colour or nan if no voxel exists there. What i would like to do is display a voxel grid with matlab like in the following picture:

[image]

Except that the vocels should be coloured with the number in the cell.

Does anyone know how to do this, if there is a library or some way to write it myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found out you can do it like this:

```
for x = 1:GridSize(1)
    for y = 1:GridSize(2)
        for z = 1:GridSize(3)

            if (~isnan(VoxelGrid(x, y, z)))

                cubeLength = VoxelGrid.resolution;

                plotcube(   [cubeLength cubeLength cubeLength], ...
                            [x, y, z], ...
                            0.9, ...
                            [colour, colour, colour])
             end
         end
     end
 end
```

This will print out a grey scale voxel representation like this:

[image]

Now i just need some help getting the colour working.

Comment: now apply the solution from you other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642826/use-matlab-colour-scheme-to-convert-float-to-rgb to get your colours

Comment: I assume `plotcube` is this function: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15161-plotcube at least the signature matches.

Comment: @Daniel Yep, i think that was what i used.

Answer (score 0):

Complete source code is given below plotting cubes in Different colors.  Remember that for obtaining the colour information, we must have Float value between <0,1>. So the input volume is normalized to shift intensity values in this range and then plotcube script is used for displaying individual cubes.
Script Used for obtaining colour is @ [Use matlab colour scheme to convert float to RGB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11642826/use-matlab-colour-scheme-to-convert-float-to-rgb). Plotting individual cubes is @ http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15161-plotcube

```
%PLOTCUBE(EDGES,ORIGIN,ALPHA,COLOR)

VoxelGrid(:,:,1)=[5 3;8 1];
VoxelGrid(:,:,2)=[9 2;7 1];

%VoxelGrid=round(20*rand(8,8,8)); %Uncomment this line to display dense volume

GridSize=size(VoxelGrid);
for x = 1:GridSize(1)
    for y = 1:GridSize(2)
        for z = 1:GridSize(3)
            if (~isnan(VoxelGrid(x, y, z)))
                cubeLength = 1;
                f = VoxelGrid(x,y,z)/max(max(max(VoxelGrid)));
                cm = colormap; % returns the current color map
                colorID = max(1, sum(f > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1])); 
                colour = cm(colorID, :); % returns your color
                plotcube([cubeLength cubeLength cubeLength],[x, y, z],0.9,[colour]);
             end
         end
     end
end
```