# Use matlab colour scheme to convert float to RGB

Tags: matlab, colors

If i have a float, for example `0.568` (float is guaranteed to be `0 -> 1`). Is there a way to convert that to RGB values (in double `[1.0, 1.0, 1.0]` or int `[255 255 255]`) under the current matlab colour scheme (ie. normal, hot, hsv, etc)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
f = 0.568; % your float

cm = colormap % returns the current color map

colorID = max(1, sum(f > [0:1/length(cm(:,1)):1])); 

myColor = cm(colorID, :) % returns your color
```

The result for `f = 0.568` is

```
myColor =

    0.8125    1.0000    0.1875
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the help for jet.

jet.colors(n) returns an array of n color values spanning the range of the color function, jet in this case.  Now all you do is scale/map your data to that 1:n range.  This is a good way to get/tweak color maps.  I used to do it all the time.

Comment: Is that an actual command, because i get Undefined variable "jet" or class "jet.colors". when i use it.

Comment: Sorry.  Try this: require(graphics)